# Object Array add only adds last record

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I am trying to add an object to an arraylist.

The object is defined as:

```
ExercisesGroup group = new ExercisesGroup();
```

Array List defined as:

```
ArrayList<ExercisesGroup> groups = new ArrayList<ExercisesGroup>();
```

I am then populating the object in a loop (rs is a result set from a database):

```
while (rs.next()){
    group.setExerciseGroupId(rs.getInt("idbodyarea"));
    group.setExerciseGroupDescription(rs.getString("bodyareadescription"));
    groups.add(group);
}
```

When I return the arraylist 'groups' the correct number of results are added, however the data is all the same, i.e. the last record is added for every slot.

```
<exerciseGroupsReturn>
        <exerciseGroupDescription>Description2</exerciseGroupDescription>
        <exerciseGroupId>2</exerciseGroupId>
 </exerciseGroupsReturn>
 <exerciseGroupsReturn>
        <exerciseGroupDescription>Description2</exerciseGroupDescription>
        <exerciseGroupId>2</exerciseGroupId>
 </exerciseGroupsReturn>
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a new instance of the object on every iteration:

```
while (rs.next()){
   group = new ExercisesGroup();
   //...
}
```

Also, it would be better if you change the declaration of `groups` variable from `ArrayList<ExercisesGroup>` to `List<ExercisesGroup>`. Refer to [What does it mean to "program to an interface"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/383947/1065197)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're creating your ExcerciseGroup outside of the loop so you're always referencing the same object. Put the ExerciseGroup constructor inside the loop.